# Amazon elastic ip setup

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web application on an amazon ec2 instance with a reachable address in the form xxxx.elasticbeanstalk.com.  I am trying to link my application to a different domain that I own.  I have created an elastic IP and linked in to my instance.  So now i have a new IP address and a public dns address.  However when i try to go to either of these address in my browser, nothing happens.  Am I supposed to wait a preset amount of time for the new IP to propagate?  Or am i do something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk routes all your traffic through a load balancer. To take advantage of this, you should point your domain to the load balancer with a CNAME record.  The security group of the instances are setup so that the load balancer's traffic is let through, but direct traffic is not.   If you need to access one of your instances directly, you will have to open up a port (80, 443, etc) in the security group that Beanstalk created.

Comment: Nice, I did not know about the load balancers.  It looks like there a few dns entries for it so I am going with the top (A) one.